# How to find a correlation to a value

Tags: python

I have a dataset of book ratings (user-id, isbn, movie-title, rating, ...) and I want to answer a question "If I like this book, I might also consider these...".

I've tried to create a pivot table from my dataset which caused an overflow error because the unstacked dataframe is too big, so I've just grouped it and have tried to use corrwith() as follows:

```
#data_p = pd.pivot_table(data, values='Book-Rating', index='User-ID', columns='ISBN') #This raises an overflow error
data_p = data.groupby(['User-ID', 'Book-Title'])['Book-Rating'].mean().to_frame()
i = int(data.index[data['Book-Title'] == 'The Fellowship of the Ring (The Lord of the Rings, Part 1)'][0])
data_p.corrwith(i)
```

...which raises

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_get_numeric_data'

I've also tried:

```
data_p.corrwith('The Fellowship of the Ring (The Lord of the Rings, Part 1)')
```

which gives the same error with 'string' object.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: corrwith expects another dataframe or series as the argument but you pass in string

Answer (score 1):

"Correlation" refers to how much two *sets* of numbers vary with each other. If you have a single number, nothing's varying, so there's nothing to compare. If you do `i = (data.index[data['Book-Title'] == 'The Fellowship of the Ring (The Lord of the Rings, Part 1)'][0]).apply(int)`, I would expect that to get rid of the current error, and throw a new error because the two things you're trying to correlate aren't the same size.

It seems odd to me that getting a pivot table is running out of memory, but `groupby` isn't. I'd recommend that you spend more effort seeing whether you can figure out that error. Maybe you typed something wrong?